# PyQt MySql driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyqt5

Использую PyQt v 5.4.
Встала задача работы с базой данных, а точнее с MySql. Открыв пару ссылок гугла понял как работать за базами данных, но не смог приконектиться к бд.

Есть следующий пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtSql
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("shop")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("admin")

print(db.open())
print(db.lastError().text())
```

Вывод следующий:

> ['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
>
> False
>
> Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

Как решать?

Comment: Если проектов много, то можно в папку c:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\ положить.

Answer (score 3):

Привет, такая же проблема была точь в точь. Перелапатил кучу ссылок, добавлял переменные среды и т.п. А помогло следующее:

1) Скачать *MySQL*  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=469272

2) Из папки `lib` скачать файл `libmysql.dll` и положить в папку с проектом.