# Ошибка при подключение к MySql: "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pyqt5

При таком коде:

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
db.setHostName('localhost')
db.setUserName('root')
db.setPassword('1234')
db.setDatabaseName('test')
db.open()
print(db.lastError().text())
```

В консоль выводится следующие:

```
python gui.py
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

Библиотеки qsqlite.dll, qsqlmysql.dll, qsqlodbc.dll, qsqlpsql.dll существуют и находятся в папке

> C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers

Использую Windows 10 x64, Python 3.6.1, PyQt 5.8, MySql 5.7.

Такой вопрос уже был задан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618588/pyqt-mysql-driver-not-loaded), но решение, которое в нем содержится, мою проблему не решило.

Что надо сделать, чтобы установить соединение с базой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PyQt MySql driver not loaded](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618588/pyqt-mysql-driver-not-loaded)

Comment: Решение, приведенное в вопросе выше, мне не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подключения нужно добавлять в среду переменных в переменную PATH полный путь к /MySQL/lib.

В моем случае полный путь выглядит так:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib

Затем перезагрузить или выйти из системы, чтобы это добавление вступило в силу, вот что я и сделал, и в чем состояло решение проблемы.